# Simultaneous scroll

Tags: javascript, scroll

I'm doing a simultaneous scroll in 2 divs, when the user scrolls div number 1, the other accompanies. The code is working but the scroll is very slow. Any suggestions? My code below

```js
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("container");


function foo() {
    var top = this.scrollTop;
    
    for (i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
        elems[i].scrollTop=top;
        top.preventDefault()
    }
  
}

for (i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    elems[i].addEventListener("scroll", foo);
}
```

```css
.container {
  height: 400px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width: 200px;
  background: Red;
  float: left;
}
.container.fixed {
  background-color: orange;
  position: fixed;
}
.container.fixed span {
  width: calc(100% - 50px);
  margin: 25px;
  background-color: black;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
}
.container.normal {
  margin-left: 220px;
  width: 800px;
}
.container.normal span {
  width: 300%;
  margin: 25px;
  background-color: black;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="container fixed">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
  </div>
    <div class="container normal">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Dont use an Eventlistener, but setInterval with an interval of 20 to 50 millis.

Comment: `top.preventDefault()` looks very wrong if `top` is a number…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should work.

```js
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("container");
var scrollState = 0;

function foo() {
    const elements = [... elems];
    const scrolled = elements.find(elem => elem.scrollTop !== scrollState);
    if(scrolled) {
        const newTop = scrolled.scrollTop;
        elements.forEach(element => {
            element.scrollTop = newTop;
        });
        scrollState = newTop;
    }
}

window.setInterval(foo, 30);
```

```css
.container {
  height: 400px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width: 200px;
  background: Red;
  float: left;
}
.container.fixed {
  background-color: orange;
  position: fixed;
}
.container.fixed span {
  width: calc(100% - 50px);
  margin: 25px;
  background-color: black;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
}
.container.normal {
  margin-left: 220px;
  width: 800px;
}
.container.normal span {
  width: 300%;
  margin: 25px;
  background-color: black;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="container fixed">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
  </div>
    <div class="container normal">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why use `window.setInterval`? When the user is not scrolling you are actually still bombarding the thread with calls that eventually is a noop because the scroll position has not changed. Not exactly the most performance solution IMHO.

Comment: Well, it's more work in idle state, true. But come on! Finding an element of two or three is nothing. This will work on any 15 years old mobile without any lags.

Comment: That's not the issue. The issue is that you're polling unnecessarily. I'm not saying your answer is wrong: it technically works, but just not the best approach.

Comment: You are right there. And of course "passive: true" is the clue. I just don't know which browser support this flag. If they nowadays all do, then ok.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the scrolling appears to be non-performant is not because of a throttling issue. It is because when you fire a scroll event from a `.container` element, it actually tries to set its own scrollTop at the same time. You should only set the scrollTop on elements that are not being actively scrolled.

To do this, don't use `e.preventDefault()` as that outright prevents any scrolling from happening. You can simply add an `if` clause in the `for` loop that checks if the current element being iterated over is the element firing the event, i.e.:

```
if (elems[i] === this) {
    elems[i].scrollTop = top;
}
```

Also, since you have no intentions to stop the scroll event from happening, I would [add the `{ passive: true }` option to improve performance](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/audits/passive-event-listeners) when binding the event listener:

```
elems[i].addEventListener("scroll", foo, { passive: true });
```

See proof-of-concept example:

```js
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("container");


function foo() {
  var top = this.scrollTop;

  for (i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    if (elems[i] !== this)
      elems[i].scrollTop = top;
  }

}

for (i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
  elems[i].addEventListener("scroll", foo, { passive: true });
}
```

```css
.container {
  height: 400px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width: 200px;
  background: Red;
  float: left;
}

.container.fixed {
  background-color: orange;
  position: fixed;
}

.container.fixed span {
  width: calc(100% - 50px);
  margin: 25px;
  background-color: black;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
}

.container.normal {
  margin-left: 220px;
  width: 800px;
}

.container.normal span {
  width: 300%;
  margin: 25px;
  background-color: black;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="container fixed">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
  <div class="container normal">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```